# Create list of arrays/zip two arrays in a list java

Tags: java, list

I had two arrays initially.

```
int [] start={4,8};
int [] finish={5,9};
```

I converted them into a list as per problem.

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.stream(start).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(list1);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.stream(finish).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(list2);

list1=[4,8]
list2=[5,9]
```

Now I want to create `newList=[[4,5],[8,9]]` 
I tried stream API with zip in java8 but the result was inconclusive.

Comment: I've suggested an edit, since you are declaring two arrays and trying to assign with invalid array syntax, and calling them lists. If you actually meant lists, then don't call them `int[]`.

Comment: @17slim I realized it later and made changes

Answer (score 3):

If you want it with streaming, it is possible after all:

```
List<Integer> a=Arrays.asList(4,8);
List<Integer> b=Arrays.asList(5,9);
List<List<Integer>> combined=IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.size(), b.size()))
                            .mapToObj(i->Arrays.asList(a.get(i),b.get(i)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(combined);
```

It will result in

> ```
> [[4, 5], [8, 9]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int[][] zip(int[] ... arrs) {
    if （arrs.length == 0)
        return new int[0][];
    int[][] zipped = new int[arrs[0].length][arrs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < zipped.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < zipped[i].length; j++)
        zipped[i][j] = arrs[j][i];
    return zipped;
}
```

Use it like that:

```
int[][] zipped = zip(arr1, arr2);
```

I am using my phone so i can't check syntax errors.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
List<int[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<int[]>();
listOfArrays.add(start);
listOfArrays.add(finish);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, as this would give the result `[{4,8},{5,9}]` rather than `[{4,5},{8,9}]`.

Comment: Isn't it what he try to do ? @Vro can you give the final result you want ?

Comment: I edited the question.Actually,it is list of list.
Ftom the above i got this result [[I@378bf509, [I@5fd0d5ae]

Comment: @josh i want [[4,5],[8,9]].
list which has first element of first list and second list.

Comment: @josh No it isn't, the question explicitly stated the list should look like `[[4,5],[8,9]]` at the end.

Comment: Actually the problem is you are talking about lists but your are trying to have array of arrays and not List of Lists.